# Set Automatic Tooltip 0dp Percentage on Google Donut Chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Using Google Charts [Donut Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#making-a-donut-chart) it handily produces a tooltip with a calculated percentage along with the text descriptor and base count.

However I'd like to adjust this to 0dp but can't see a way to do this in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#configuration-options) without doing HTML tooltips which seem to be overkill for a simple rounding of a decimal point.

[image: example donut chart]

You can see the issue here, where it's shown to 1dp as there's more to it, however, here it's rounded to 0dp due to it being an integer:

[image: example donut chart 2]

So, for consistency and ease for viewers, I'd like to just round this all off at 0dp.

The code I'm using is:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['NPS', 'Count'],
                ['Detractor', 25],
                ['Neutal',    31],
                ['Promoter',  48],
            ]);
            
            var options = {
                legend: 'none',
                pieSliceText: 'none',
                pieHole: 0.7,
                slices: {
                    0: { color: '#232944' },
                    1: { color: '#a5a5a5' },
                    2: { color: '#a9d136' }
                }
            };
            
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="donutchart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is not an option to format the percentage value shown in the tooltip.
the only option is a custom tooltip.

see following working snippet.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['NPS', 'Count'],
    ['Detractor', 25],
    ['Neutal',    31],
    ['Promoter',  48],
  ]);

  var groupData = google.visualization.data.group(
    data,
    [{column: 0, type: 'string', modifier: function () {return 'Total';}}],
    [{
      column: 1,
      type: 'number',
      label: 'Total',
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum
    }]
  );
  var total = groupData.getValue(0, 1);

  var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: '#,##0'
  });
  var formatPercent = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: '#,##0%'
  });

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      var label = dt.getValue(row, 0);
      var value = dt.getValue(row, 1);
      var percent = '';
      if (total > 0) {
        percent = ' (' + formatPercent.formatValue(value / total) + ')';
      }
      return label + '\n' + formatNumber.formatValue(value) + percent;
    },
    role: 'tooltip',
    type: 'string'
  }]);

  var options = {
    legend: 'none',
    pieSliceText: 'none',
    pieHole: 0.7,
    slices: {
      0: { color: '#232944' },
      1: { color: '#a5a5a5' },
      2: { color: '#a9d136' }
    },
    tooltip: {
      textStyle: {
        bold: true
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
  chart.draw(view, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="donutchart"></div>
```

Comment: Well, it wasn't the answer I wanted, but, what I expected - thanks!